# Laravel 6 | Form request validation error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have a trouble with a form. It does not show validation errors when textarea is filled with lots of text.

I read the following somewhere

> When validation fails, Laravel redirects the user back to the previous
>   page with the error messages and the original data that they submitted

Considering the textarea field houses so much text (e.g. data), it's
too much for the session to handle -- so therefore it silently fails
and the session data isn't flashed. Most browsers only support ~4080
bytes of data in a cookie, which translates to roughly 1024 characters
if I remember correctly.

If I change `SESSION_DRIVER=cookie` to `SESSION_DRIVER=file` in the `.env` file, it works perfectly but, according to official documentation, sessions will be stored in storage/framework/sessions so it will take up disk space.

Any recommendation?

Comment: The session cookie does not store the contents of the session; that would be very insecure. It only holds a key to find it on the server.

Comment: Hello, consider using redis/memcached for session and cache driver. All problems are gone and the app runs much better! I also got this problems awhile ago, but soon realized That I should not spend much time with this and should move to redis.

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization - session data will likely not require a significant amount of storage. IMO - leave the cookie driver as file and move on.

Comment: Yes, it will take up disk space. So use the session wisely. You can leverage cache to use share identical data between user. And you may consider use Redis or Database driver for your session, and they also take up disk space.

Comment: can you show your code or more briefly explain